# node red to asyncio-mqtt debug

Tags: python, python-asyncio, mqtt

I am experimenting around with Node Red and running a mosquito broker on the same Ubuntu instance. The client MQTT devices I am running [asyncio-mqtt](https://github.com/sbtinstruments/asyncio-mqtt) on a separate Ubuntu device.

In node red just 2 mqtt blocks for an in and an out:

[image]

The value of `31` is from the asyncio-mqtt `advanced_example` [python script](https://github.com/sbtinstruments/asyncio-mqtt#:%7E:text=install%20asyncio-mqtt-,advanced%20use) (scroll down to advanced uses) in this repo publishing data to the message bus on topic `floors/#` which seems to work great.

But I am stumped trying to publish a message from node red to the Python script running the `advanced_example`.

In the node red screenshot where the blue arrow is I can use an inject node to publish a string `Testing123` to topic `floors/get/temps` which works and in my Python script running the advanced example I have an `await client.subscribe("floors/#")`. I can see `Testing123` string in the cmd prompt on the Python script that is coming from Node Red.

***Where I am stuck is*** I cannot seem to create some Boolean statement to flag a particular message. For example is this legit at all? I am trying to flag the Node Red message published Testing123 but for what ever reason the `if payload_ == "Testing123"` is never True. The `type(payload_)` is string too.

```
async def log_messages(messages, template):
    async for message in messages:
        payload_ = template.format(message.payload.decode())
        print("log_messages def hit ",payload_)
        if payload_ == "Testing123":
            print("YES payload_ == Testing123, DO SOMETHING")
        else:
            print("payload_ not == Testing123")
```

Any tips greatly appreciated, I feel like I am missing some sort of a callback or something to "flag" some incoming MQTT message.

This is the entire `advanced_example` sorry alot of code:

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import AsyncExitStack, asynccontextmanager
from random import randrange
from asyncio_mqtt import Client, MqttError
import configs
import json



broker_url = configs.login_info["broker_url"]
username = configs.login_info["username"]
password = configs.login_info["password"]


async def advanced_example():
    # We  context managers. Let's create a stack to help
    # us manage them.
    async with AsyncExitStack() as stack:
        # Keep track of the asyncio tasks that we create, so that
        # we can cancel them on exit
        tasks = set()
        stack.push_async_callback(cancel_tasks, tasks)

        # Connect to the MQTT broker
        client = Client(broker_url,
                username=username,
                password=password)
        await stack.enter_async_context(client)

        # You can create any number of topic filters
        topic_filters = (
            "floors/+/humidity",
            "floors/rooftop/#",
            "floors/get/temps"
            #  Try to add more filters!
        )
        for topic_filter in topic_filters:
            # Log all messages that matches the filter
            manager = client.filtered_messages(topic_filter)
            messages = await stack.enter_async_context(manager)
            template = f'[topic_filter="{topic_filter}"] {{}}'
            task = asyncio.create_task(log_messages(messages, template))
            tasks.add(task)

        # Messages that doesn't match a filter will get logged here
        messages = await stack.enter_async_context(client.unfiltered_messages())
        task = asyncio.create_task(log_messages(messages, "[unfiltered] {}"))
        tasks.add(task)

        # Subscribe to topic(s)
        #  Note that we subscribe *after* starting the message
        # loggers. Otherwise, we may miss retained messages.
        await client.subscribe("floors/#")

        # Publish a random value to each of these topics
        topics = (
            "floors/basement/humidity",
            "floors/rooftop/humidity",
            "floors/rooftop/illuminance",
            #  Try to add more topics!
        )
        task = asyncio.create_task(post_to_topics(client, topics))
        tasks.add(task)

        # Wait for everything to complete (or fail due to, e.g., network
        # errors)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def post_to_topics(client, topics):
    while True:
        for topic in topics:
            message = randrange(100)
            print(f'[topic="{topic}"] Publishing message={message}')
            await client.publish(topic, message, qos=1)
            await asyncio.sleep(60)



async def log_messages(messages, template):
    async for message in messages:
        payload_ = template.format(message.payload.decode())
        print("log_messages def hit ",payload_)
        if payload_ == "Testing123":
            print("YES payload_ == Testing123, DO SOMETHING")
        else:
            print("payload_ not == Testing123")
            
            


async def cancel_tasks(tasks):
    for task in tasks:
        if task.done():
            continue
        task.cancel()
        try:
            await task
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass

async def main():
    # Run the advanced_example indefinitely. Reconnect automatically
    # if the connection is lost.
    reconnect_interval = 3  # [seconds]
    while True:
        try:
            await advanced_example()
        except MqttError as error:
            print(f'Error "{error}". Reconnecting in {reconnect_interval} seconds.')
        finally:
            await asyncio.sleep(reconnect_interval)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Removed node-red tag as this is purely to do with consuming messages in Python, how you publish it is not relevant.

Comment: You are comparing a formatted log message (`payload_ = template.format(message.payload.decode())` will result in `payload_` being set to something like `[topic_filter="floors/get/temps"] Testing123`) with what you expect the raw message to be (`Testing123`). Try `if message.payload.decode() == "Testing123"`. Note that these questions are easier to answer if you include the programs output.

Comment: Hey that worked! Thanks so much @Brits. Can you post an answer and ill hit the green check?

Comment: Sure. However I'm also going to vote to close this because I don't believe the way it was resolved will be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments change `if payload_ == "Testing123":` to `if message.payload.decode() == "Testing123"`.

Your code does not work because `payload_ = template.format(message.payload.decode())` applies a template to the message payload - if the message is `Testing123` then `payload_` will be set to something like `[topic_filter="floors/get/temps"] Testing123` (which will fail your equality test).